# PHP array Incremental

Tags: php, arrays

This is the random array i have, it's not always start at 2012 and end at 2017.

```
Array
(
    [2012] => 1
    [2014] => 1
    [2015] => 1
    [2016] => 4
    [2017] => 1
)
```

i have an array like this, and i want it to be like this

```
Array
(
    [2012] => 1 //The start, not add
    [2014] => 2 //2012 + 2014 = 1 + 1 = 2
    [2015] => 3 //2012 + 2014 + 2015 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
    [2016] => 7 //2012 + 2014 + 2015 + 2016 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 4 = 7 
    [2017] => 8 //2012 + 2014 + 2015 + 2016 + 2017 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 1 = 8
)
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: You can do this with a loop. What have you already tried to do this and what was the specific problem you ran into?

Comment: You can do it. Its so easy. Go On.

Comment: Ok thank you guys, i've got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    2012 => 1, // 1
    2014 => 1, // 2
    2015 => 1, // 3
    2016 => 4, // 7
    2017 => 1  // 8
);

// Getting the all keys of array
$keys = array_keys($arr);

// Make a new array to set the executed values 
$arr1 = array();

// loop the array
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $sum = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        $sum += $arr[$keys[$j]];
    }
    // set values to new array
    $arr1[$keys[$i]] = $sum;
}

// print the new array
print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: Kindly explain what you did. Posting only code does not help completely.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I'll fix that.